# Adding a class if condition matches in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

I have just started using angular js. I am using it with CodeIgniter. I am trying to add a {class="active"} if a condition matches.

I am trying to add a active class to a `<li>` if its title matches with the last segment of url.

i.e.

```
 if(title of this nav_menu matches with the last uri segment)
    add "active" class
 else
    do nothing
```

My code is as follows :

**header.php**

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav" ng-app="" ng-controller="menuController">
    <li ng-repeat="x in menus" ng-class="{'active': x.name = scope}">
        <a ng-href="http://{{ x.link}}">{{ x.name }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**footer.php**

```
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>


<script>
    function menuController($scope) {

        $scope.menus = [ {
            name : "Home",
            link : "projects/test/home"
        }, {
            name : "Daily Special",
            link : "projects/caesar/daily-especial"
        }, {
            name : "Menu",
            link : "projects/test/menu"
        }, {
            name : "Special",
            link : "projects/test/special"
        }, {
            name : "Gallery",
            link : "projects/test/gallery"
        }, {
            name : "About us",
            link : "projects/test/about-us"
        }, {
            name : "Contact",
            link : "projects/test/contact"
        } ];

        $scope.current = '<?php echo $this->uri->segment(2); ?>';

    }
</script>
```

I think the problematic step is $scope.current = 'uri->segment(2); ?>';

Comment: Do you mean something like: `ng-class="{'active': x.name.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-') == x.link.substr(link.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, link.length)}"`?

Answer (score 5):

Here is how ng-class works, say for the below example

```
ng-class="{ 'active': menu.IsCurrentTab, 'inactive': !menu.IsCurrentTab }"
```

class `active` will be added if the scope variable `menu` has `IsCurrentTab` value `true`. Else class `inactive` will be used.

In your case firstly I do not know what this code of your's does

```
$scope.current = '<?php echo $this->uri->segment(2); ?>';
```

If this is putting the current menu name in the `$scope.current` variable, then all you need to do is

```
<li ng-repeat="x in menus" ng-class="{'active': x.name == current}" >
```

Hope this helps.

Edit:

Would want you to check if the value is filled in your $scope.current variable.

Comment: Thanks Yasser. Could you simplify that a bit?

Comment: Silly of me, I used x.name = scope, when it had to be x.name == scope :D.